# Get correct timezone name from time format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.s+zzzzzz

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I am working with an api that returns time in an iso standard (`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.s+zzzzzz`)
    Where:

```
yyyy is the year

mm (first) is the month

dd is the day

T is a separator indicating that time-of-day follows

hh is the hour on a 24-hour clock

mm (second) is the minute

ss is whole seconds

s (optional) is the fractional second

zzzzzz is the time zone
```

> eg 2015-07-31T13:00:00.000+03:00

I would like to get the correct timezone from `+03:00`

What i have tried based from other solutions here on stackoverflow:

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-07-31T13:00:00.000+03:00');
$newtz = date_timezone_get($date);
$offset= timezone_name_get($newtz);
$timezone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $offset) * 36;
$timezone_name = timezone_name_from_abbr('', $offset, true);
echo $timezone_name;
```

The above code outputs: `Europe/Helsinki` but i am expecting `Africa/Nairobi`

Question is how do I make the code output `Africa/Nairobi`?

Also what about where there exists two timezones with the same offset eg:
`Europe/Minsk` and `Africa/Nairobi` have offsets of `+03:00`

Comment: * how do i make the code output 'Africa/Nairobi'* - from time shift - never

Comment: Why? I am would like to use the value to convert '2015-07-31T13:00:00.000+03:00'  to 2015-07-31 13:00 EAT currently i get 2015-07-31 13:00 EEST Which is wrong

Comment: nothing wrong, but +3000 is simultaneously in too many region of Earth

Comment: I understand. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, it's a one-to-many relationship (like 1:50 or so). There might be a slightly cleaner way to do this, but here's what you're after:

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-07-31T13:00:00.000+03:00');
$newtz = date_timezone_get($date);
$offset_string= timezone_name_get($newtz);
$offset = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $offset_string) * 36;
$full_list_of_timezones = timezone_abbreviations_list();
foreach ($full_list_of_timezones as $array1) {
    foreach ($array1 as $array2) {
        if ($array2[offset] == $offset) {
            echo $array2[timezone_id]."<br>\n";
        }
    }
}
```